# How to Refactor Java web project package structure so that conform to microservice?

Tags: java, maven, microservices

We have such a mess java web project need to be refactor.First, we need to confirm the new package structure or maven project structure.

As the microservice is very hot now, we want to design the  package structure that conform to microservice (which I do not know much).
So we can take less effort to refactor the project to microservice in the second phase.

Is there such a 'silver bullet'?

Comment: Spring cloud can help you to do a quick microservice http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/, or also https://www.lightbend.com/lagom

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't take project decisions basing on what's "hot" right now. What are you gonna do next year, when something else will be "hot"? Perform refactoring again? The microservice architecture will be fine only for several types of projects, but not for all of them. It is possible to achieve good architecture and clean code without microservices. First of all, you should perform a deeper analysis of your project and it's domain. You should think if such type of architecture will really help you and why. In microservice architecture, you can also have a mess but on a different level of abstraction. It can be a subject of long article or publication. I suggest you, to perform a deeper research before starting any concrete work.

> Is there such a 'silver bullet'?

Of course not.